# Cannot find System.Windows.Controls.dll for Silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, treeview, autocompletebox

Where can I find System.Windows.Controls.dll for Silverlight 3? I need it to be able to use the TreeView control and the AutoCompleteBox control. Toolkit November 2009 is installed but the dll that I need was not included.

Answer (score 3):

The `AutoCompleteBox` and the `TreeView` are part of the SDK not the Toolkit.  The dlls that contains them are found typically at the following paths respectively:-

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Libraries\Client\System.Windows.Controls.Input.dll
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Libraries\Client\System.Windows.Controls.dll

(Note use "Program Files (x86)" on 64 bit systems)

However you should add them simply by using the "Add Reference" dialog, they have the component names of `System.Windows.Controls.Input` and `System.Windows.Controls`.

What is in the Toolkit and what is in the SDK can be a bit confusing.  This is typically because things have a habit of migrating from Toolkit to the SDK once it matures.  A clever bit of QA that.